# Error con MercadoPagoSDK ios

Tags: flutter, ios, mercadopago

Estoy testeando mi app y cuándo la quiero ejecutar en un dispositivo de IOs me da el error `Error runing pod install`, si me muevo a la carpeta ios y ejecuto `pod install` me da el error:

```
**[!] Error installing MercadoPagoSDK
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/mercadopago/px-ios.git /var/folders/y4/6qf0hlld2k36tt90_hrv5g380000gn/T/d20230518-15114-4a4z3g --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 4.32.4**

Cloning into '/var/folders/y4/6qf0hlld2k36tt90_hrv5g380000gn/T/d20230518-15114-4a4z3g'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/mercadopago/px-ios.git/' not found.
```

A alguien más le paso?

Comment: Sí, me pasa. Ese repositorio no existe si intento buscarlo. Ni idea de dónde salió esa URL que intentas clonar.

Comment: Hola! El repo lleva varios días de baja o en privado. Desde nuestra empresa consultamos con el soporte de Mercadopago pero no nos supieron explicar por qué no está disponible. Te diría que insistas con ellos a ver si tenés más suerte. Como alternativa estamos viendo de hacer la implementación con el SDK de JS e integrarlo vía un WebView.

Comment: Si, generé un reclamo a la gente de Mercadopago, veremos que me dicen, muchas gracias @RobertoVaccaro